# Very slow MySQL delete

Tags: mysql, innodb

So I'm trying to delete a number of rows from a reasonably large mysql(innodb)table.

The query i'm trying to use do this is as follows:

`delete from item where id in (select id from items_to_be_deleted);`

`item` is a 70'000'000 row table, and `items_to_be_deleted` is a 1'000'000 row table.

My query just never seems to finish, even if i add an incredibly small limit to it. (`delete from item where id in (select id from items_to_be_deleted) LIMIT 10;`

If i run `select id from items_to_be_deleted` it returns nearly instantaneously, it is just a table with a primary key (id) and another varchar field.

Whats wrong with my query that it is taking so long / never seems to finish?

Comment: Check http://oysteing.blogspot.com/2014/07/a-multi-table-trick-to-speed-up-single.html , and try DELETE item FROM item WHERE ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IN clause work as a iteration of OR clause  so you could avoid this using  an inner join based on the same subquery used  for the IN   clause

```
delete item
from item
inner join  (
  select id 
  from items_to_be_deleted
) t on t.id  = item.id
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `JOIN`?

```
DELETE i
FROM Item i
INNER JOIN items_to_be_deleted i2 ON i.ID = i2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Other way can be to use EXISTS operator with dependent subquery:

```
DELETE i FROM item i 
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM items_to_be_deleted WHERE id = i.id
)
```

Comment: pretty sure this co-related subquery will go wrong somehow.. as `id` is not fully qualified or aliased and the id column exists in both tables.. i would be temped to write `DELETE FROM item 
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM items_to_be_deleted WHERE items_to_be_deleted.id = item.id
)` and use fully qualified

Comment: I always use it that way. unaliased `id` relates to correct inner table because outer tables have less priority than inner for subquery. Also, I never use table names as alias, it's better to add an alias for ..._deleted one, imo.

Comment: *"I always use it that way. unaliased id relates to correct inner table because outer tables have less priority than inner"* Well it is tricky trusting the optimizer to do that, as your query does not [work](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q8xKgrnkhvbwQc7LaeaWoW/1r)

Comment: Can't open a link. It is private may be?

Comment: No it wasn't private, try this one https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q8xKgrnkhvbwQc7LaeaWoW/3 then?

Comment: I fix a query by `delete i from` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ZdDtUAM3tqML5BQUxVdNH/0 Just forget that, thanks.

Comment: *"Just forget that, thanks. "* No problem but indeed +1 fool the optimizer you want to delete from "multiple tables" as `DELETE <columns> FROM ...`  is the multiple-table delete syntax, wierd that when you use a alias that is required i also didn't know this as i almost use no co-related subqueries, consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ZdDtUAM3tqML5BQUxVdNH/2)

Comment: I think you need 8.0.16 for EXISTS to be efficient (converted to semijoin).

Comment: @oysteing, can we then use `WHERE 1 IN (SELECT 1...)` in <8 versions for that optimization?

Comment: @vp_arth If you use an IN subquery, it will be transformed to semijoin in 5.6 and later.  However, if your subquery refers to columns of an outer table, the semijoin materialization strategy will not be available, but other semijoin strategies can be used.  From 8.0.16, both EXISTS and IN can use all semijoin strategies.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting a million rows, do it in chunks.  Otherwise, the building of the undo log will be a killer.  It must save all million previous rows, and later really toss them.

Since it is only a small percentage of the table I won't recommend copying the rows to *keep* into a new table.

Multiple ways to make a `DELETE` fast:
https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

One thing to try to achieve, since there are 69 rows to keep for every 1 to toss:  Try to have the 1M-row table drive the query.  Most solutions involve scanning through all 70M rows, checking each one against the smaller table.